# Moving website from SSL domain to a subdomain without SSL

Tags: ssl, migration, opencart

I migrated an existing OpenCart website from one hosting where it had SSL certificate for the domain, to a new hosting and a subdomain **without** SSL certificate.

Now when I open the subdomain I automatically get redirected to https.

I added this code in my `.htaccess` file but I still get the same problem :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Best solution would be to get https for your subdomain.

Comment: It worked :) I was looking for some other way around this but in the and I had to install an SSL certificate. Thanks

Comment: While it's a good idea to have an SSL certificate, it will be to your benefit to figure out what's going on  with the redirect. You shouldn't install a certificate simply because mysterious things are happening that you don't understand.